# Display data in decimal format while editing cell value

Tags: java, swing, jtable

while editing cell value in JTable it's value suddenly appears in exponential form(i.e. 1.7E10) instead of being displayed in normal user friendly form.

How can I change the number formatting while editing cell value?

...

The Solution Was really simple, had to create my own TableCellEditor like that:

```
 public static class Double2DecimalEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JComponent component = new JTextField();
    private NumberFormat nf;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        System.out.println("getCellEditorValue");
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#,###.###");
        String text = ((JTextField)component).getText();
        System.out.println("TEXT = " + ((JTextField)component).getText());
        return nf.format(Double.parseDouble(text));
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        System.out.println("getCellEditorComponent");
        Double data = Double.valueOf(value.toString().replace(",", ""));
        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");
        ((JTextField)component).setText(nf.format(data));
        ((JTextField)component).setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        return component;
    }
}
```

THANKS to everybody for advices!

Comment: If I understand you correctly the number is displayed in a user friendly form and _while entering data_ it is changed? As in: when I have 170000000 and add another zero the data is reformatted to 1.7E9 ? If so, can you show some code? Do you apply formatting to the textfield/spinner you enter the data into while editing?

Comment: yes you are right, in case if number has more then 9 digits when I am double clicking on a cell to edit it it's value is displayed like 1.2E10 instead of 12000000000.

The only formatting applied is:


public static class NumberEditor extends STableCellEditor {
    public NumberEditor() {
      ((JTextField) getComponent()).setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as i see its this line that breaks your code

```
textField.setText((value != null) ? value.toString() : "");
```

this happens in the javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor#DefaultCellEditor that is used by the JTable.

You will have to add your own editor that applies formatting .

should be similar too

```
table.setDefaultEditor(Double.class, new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField())
    {
      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent( JTable table, Object value,
                                                    boolean isSelected,
                                                    int row, int column )
      {
        String formattedvalue = formatyourvalue(value);
        delegate.setValue(formattedvalue);
        return editorComponent;
      }
    });
```

applied to the example you change the makeTable with

```
  private static JTable makeSampleTable()
  {
    String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Boolean", "Double"};
    Object[][] data = {{"AAA", 12, true, 111111111111.15},
                       {"BBB", 1, false, 11199999111.15}, {"CCC", 2, true, 1155555511111.15},};
    DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public Class<?> getColumnClass( int column )
      {
        return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
      }
    };
    JTable table = new JTable(m);
    TableColumnModel tm = table.getColumnModel();
    tm.getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new Double2DecimalRenderer());
    table.setDefaultEditor(Double.class, new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField())
    {
      public Component getTableCellEditorComponent( JTable table, Object value,
                                                    boolean isSelected,
                                                    int row, int column )
      {
        NumberFormat nf;
        nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        if ( ( value != null ) && ( value instanceof Number ) )
          {
          Number numberValue = (Number) value;
          delegate.setValue(nf.format(numberValue.doubleValue()));
          }
        else
          {
          delegate.setValue(value);
          }
        return editorComponent;
      }
    });
    return table;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the necessary solution.

Answer (score 2):

here is SSCCE that demonstrated issue with Double (and by implements NumberRenderer too),

[image]

just my curiosity, I leaving to answering this question, maybe there is/are better workaround if is there any exist

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Back2DefaultSortingTest {

    private static JTable makeSampleTable() {
        String[] columnNames = {"String", "Integer", "Boolean", "Double"};
        Object[][] data = {{"AAA", 12, true, 111111111111.15},
            {"BBB", 1, false, 11199999111.15}, {"CCC", 2, true, 1155555511111.15},};
        DefaultTableModel m = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(m);
        TableColumnModel tm = table.getColumnModel();
        tm.getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(new Double2DecimalRenderer());
        return table;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JScrollPane(makeSampleTable()));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(p);
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class Double2DecimalRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private int precision = 0;
        private Number numberValue;
        private NumberFormat nf;

        public Double2DecimalRenderer() {
            super();
            setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
            precision = 0;
            nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        }

        @Override
        public void setValue(Object value) {
            if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Number)) {
                numberValue = (Number) value;
                value = nf.format(numberValue.doubleValue());
            }
            super.setValue(value);
        }
    }

    private Back2DefaultSortingTest() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the problem is exactly as you have clarified and special thanks for the screenshot.. Have no Idea how to fix that..